# How to clean up remnants of old versions?

Tags: 14.04, update-manager, cleanup

I have a laptop with 14.04 installed on it, and I've had Ubuntu on this machine since 12.04. I notice that I have "duplicates" (old versions) of some programs, namely update manager, belonging to both the older versions and the new. Is there a good way to clean these out of here?

Comment: How can you tell they are duplicated? Do you get multiple launchers when searching in the dash?

Comment: Yes, I do. And they launch clearly different versions of the program.

Comment: That's odd. Can you provide the output of `dpkg -l` (this will generate a list of installed packages). As this will generate a lot of output, use http://paste.ubuntu.com or `dpkg -l | pastebinit` (this will copy the output and save it in paste.ubuntu.com, giving you a link)

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7880392/

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get autoremove` or `sudo apt-get autoclean` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't give you an answer to your problem, but I can give you some tips to try to understand what's happening.

When you upgraded your system all the applications installed with `apt-get`/Software Center had to be also upgraded, and when a package is upgraded it replaces the previous version, so I really don't know how you can have 2 versions of `Update Manager`.

If any of those apps where manually installed, then you may have two versions (the one you manually installed and one managed by the system). In this case just remove one and use the other.

Regarding the duplicate launchers: they are stored in `/usr/share/applications` (system-wide) and `~/.local/share/applications` (only visible to your user). You can check those two locations and see if there are no duplicated launchers.

If you have problems identifying which launcher belongs to each application, you can launch each duplicated item and run the following command in a terminal:

```
$ xprop | grep DESKTOP_FILE
```

Your cursor will change to a cross. Then click in the window of that application. You may get (not all applications give you this information) an output similar the following:

```
$ xprop | grep DESKTOP_FILE
_NET_WM_DESKTOP_FILE(STRING) = "/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop"
```

In my case I clicked in the terminal window. You would click on both the versions launched and hopefully would get two different paths there.

Comment: Thanks. I used that to find the location of the desktop file for the second updated and deleted it. The program's still there somewhere, but I can't see it any more.